# Creating Schrödinger cat states with trapped ions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, quantum-optics, schroedingers-cat

We will consider an ion is in an harmonic trap. The ion has two internal states \lvert g\rangle and \lvert s\rangle and it interacts with a laser that induces a state-dependent force. The quantum dynamics is governed by the Hamiltonian

$$H = H_R+H_f$$
$$H_R = \Omega (\lvert s\rangle\langle g\rvert+\lvert g\rangle\langle s\rvert)$$
$$H_f = g (\lvert s\rangle\langle s\rvert-\lvert g\rangle\langle g\rvert)(a^{\dagger}+a)$$

HR induces Rabi oscillations between internal states. Hf describes an optical force that depends on the state of the
ion. Note that the operator $(a^\dagger + a)$ is proportional to the position of the ion. The force’s sign depends on the internal state of the ion, such that

$$\lvert s\rangle \rightarrow H_f = g(a^\dagger + a) $$
$$\lvert g\rangle \rightarrow H_f = -g(a^\dagger + a) $$

1. Imagine the ion is initially in the ground state
   $$\lvert\psi_1\rangle = \lvert g\rangle\lvert0\rangle\,,$$ where $\lvert g\rangle$ is the electronic ground state and $\lvert0\rangle$ is the ground state of the vibrational degrees of freedom (zero phonons). We consider that there is no applied force and the Rabi term HR acts for a time $t=\frac{\pi}{4\Omega}$ . After that, the state of the ion is
   $$\lvert\psi_2\rangle = (a\lvert g\rangle + b\lvert s\rangle)\lvert0\rangle$$
   Calculate $a$ and $b$.
2. Now we turn off the Rabi term $(\Omega = 0)$ and let the state-dependent force act for a time $\tau$. Show that the state of the ion is
   $$\lvert\psi_2\rangle = a\lvert g\rangle\lvert\alpha\rangle + b\lvert s\rangle\lvert − \alpha\rangle$$
   and calculate the value of $\alpha$.

I have already solved question number 1 by applying the Schrödinger equation obtaining that

$$\lvert \psi\rangle_2 = (\cos(\Omega t)\lvert g\rangle - i\sin(\Omega t)\lvert s\rangle)\lvert 0\rangle$$

and therefore in $t=\frac{\pi}{4\Omega}$
$$\lvert \psi\rangle_2 = \left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\lvert g\rangle - i\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\lvert s\rangle\right)\lvert 0\rangle$$

I have some doubts about the second question. What I have tried is the following
\begin{align}
\lvert{\psi(t)}\rangle_3 &= e^{-iH_f t}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\lvert g\rangle-i\lvert s\rangle)\lvert 0\rangle
\\&=e^{-i(\lvert s\rangle\langle s\rvert-\lvert g\rangle\langle s\rvert)t}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\lvert g\rangle-i\lvert s\rangle)\otimes e^{-ig(a^\dagger +a )t}\lvert 0\rangle
\\&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e^{it}\lvert g\rangle-e^{-it}i\lvert s\rangle)\otimes e^{-ig(a^\dagger +a )t}\lvert 0\rangle\,.
\end{align}
I think that

$$e^{-ig(a^\dagger + a)t}\lvert 0\rangle$$

should be something proportional to $\lvert \alpha\rangle = \lvert{-igt}\rangle$
(as it reminds to the displacement operator). But the displacement operator is proportional to $e^{a^\dagger - a}$,
so im a bit confused. Could you help me? Thank you.

Comment: `\ket` and `\bra` are (AFAIK?) nonstandard LaTeX commands that MathJax (which is used on this site for rendering equations) does not have; so you have to change those to `\vert\rangle` and `\langle\vert` pairs.

Comment: I think I got the edits right this time.  Check to make sure I didn't mess anything up.

Comment: @march Yes, it is right. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general form of the displacement operator is
$$
\hat{D}(\alpha) = e^{\alpha\hat{a}^{\dagger} - \alpha^*\hat{a}}\,,
$$
which can also be written as
$$
\hat{D}(\alpha) = e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}e^{\alpha\hat{a}^{\dagger}}e^{- \alpha^*\hat{a}} =
e^{|\alpha|^2/2}e^{- \alpha^*\hat{a}}e^{\alpha\hat{a}^{\dagger}}\,.
$$
You can use either of these last two forms to compute the action of $e^{-ig(\hat{\alpha}^{\dagger}+\hat{\alpha})t} = e^{(-igt)\hat{\alpha}^{\dagger}-(-igt)^*\hat{\alpha}}$. But, we already know that $\hat{D}(\alpha)\lvert 0\rangle = \lvert \alpha\rangle$, so really you just need to use that.